# How to create this kind of facebook page with iframes

Tags: facebook, iframe, facebook-like

I came across this Facebook page in which it has a video that you can only view if you like the page.

http://www.facebook.com/truerest

Just wondering how I would go about doing this with the new iframe style facebook pages?

Comment: You can view the video if you change the visibility in CSS to normal, there is [no need](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wWUswrIMxzQ) to like the page.

Comment: I appreciate that, but I dont actually want to watch the video, I want the function of other content appearing once the like button has been pressed.

Comment: @jeremy that's your choice to watch it or not. I would watch it if I were you. you will really get the idea how facebook apps are done after that. the video also show how to handle coupons or some other stuff.

Comment: tugberk, that wasnt aimed at you, that was aimed at Hakre - he just pointed me in the direction of the video on that facebook page - not what i wanted.  What you provided was more up my street, thanks

Comment: @jeremy oww, sorry for that. I saw 'video' on your comment and thought that it was for me. also, between April 12 - 14, Jim Zimmerman will talk about Facebook development on MIX11 as well. here is the link : http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/MIX/MIX11/OPN06 (do not forget the vote my answer up if it helps) (if it solves your problem, pls mark it as answer)

Comment: @jeremy - you can find some hints on how to do that in the code, mainly CSS and HTML attributes. Dig in with firebug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do you like watching geek-talks with codes? if so, watch this video ;

Building Facebook Apps with Microsoft .NET and Deploying to Windows Azure : http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/MIX/MIX10/EX23

**NOTE** this link is the direct link for the video wmv file if you wanna download it;

http://ecn.channel9.msdn.com/o9/mix/10/wmv-hq/EX23.wmv